# Can a class check if it exists in an SWF or in an FLA?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2, swc

I have an AS2 component which I need to behave differently in an SWF from an FLA.  Can it determine its state programmatically?

Part of the problem here may be too that when I compile it as an SWC it probably doesn't think it's in an FLA anymore.

Since I need to port this to AS3 at some point, I wouldn't mind AS3 solutions too.

Comment: Please refine your question its very confusing.  A swc is an archive containing a swf and a catalog.xml file.  Regardless of the source a swf is just a swf, and a swc is just a swc.  Please try to explain what you're doing at a slightly higher level, in other words whats the end goal of this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless wvxvw is correct and you're doing something with live preview, your code always runs as a swf. Swc and fla don't execute anything.

It is possible to get different behavior in different contexts. The easiest way would be to set a flag via swfobject & flashvars (when running in the browser obviously).